# Is AT command the only way to connect from Arduino to esp2866?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

If I am programming an arduino and I wanted to communicate with the internet thru the esp2866 then is AT command the only thing that I can do?

I see a lot of this in the web

```
void loop() {
 valSensor = getSensorData();
 String getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ field +"="+String(valSensor);
sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");
 sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,15,"OK");
 sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">");
 esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;
 sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");
}
```

If I set my Board -> Arduino Uno, I was thinking I can use the following library https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.4_a/esp8266wifi/readme.html

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
 
const char* ssid     = "my-ssid";
const char* password = "my-password";
 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
```

But I am getting

```
exit status 1
ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory
```

Looks like the following library is only available when you set the Board-> Generic ESP8266 Module and is only used when you want to program the ESP8266 in the Arduino IDE?  Is this correct?

So in my question, does it mean that to communicate from the Arduino into the internet, I will be sending the AT command and communicate thru the SoftwareSerial.h?

Comment: you could use a library which has a nice standard Arduino networking interface over the AT commands. The WiFiEsp library for old AT firmware or my WiFiEspAT for AT 1.7+ https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is AT command the only thing that I can do?

No. The AT commands are provided by the AT command firmware. You can replace that firmware with whatever you want.

It is common to write your own software for the ESP8266 to do your communication for you and communicate with other devices (including an Arduino) in whatever way is suitable.

Many times you don't even need the Arduino any more as the ESP8266 can do everything (it struggles with analog signals as there is only one rather inferior ADC pin).

> Looks like the following library is only available when you set the Board-> Generic ESP8266 Module and is only used when you want to program the ESP8266 in the Arduino IDE? Is this correct?

That is correct. That is for when you are writing your own ESP8266 firmware to replace the AT firmware.

> So in my question, does it mean that to communicate from the Arduino into the internet, I will be sending the AT command and communicate thru the SoftwareSerial.h?

Only if you retain the AT firmware on the ESP8266. To be honest that firmware is terrible and all the tutorials are bad. You should at the first available opportunity learn to program the ESP8266 directly and maybe retire the Arduino unless you need to use it as a glorified IO expander.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes this is where I am very much confused.  I see a lot of google search results like this https://www.instructables.com/id/Using-ESP-01-and-Arduino-UNO/.  and it looks like it is passing only AT commands into the ESP2866.  I am studying this for now so I cannot remove the Arduino in the equation.  But to satisfy my curiosity, if I don't replace the AT firmware then I could only use AT commands right?

Comment: Also another question please, I followed the following link https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-arduino-ide and I was able to make it work but my ESP8266  is not from Adafruit.  I noticed that after doing so, the AT commands stop working.  Does it mean that my firmware now is that of the https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.4_a/esp8266wifi/readme.html?  I am a bit confused on this parts.  I set my ESP board in bootload mode and then uploaded the blink.  After that my AT commands stop working when I used the serial monitor.

Comment: The AT firmware only responds to AT commands. That 's what it is and what it does. If you want to use anything other than AT commands then you will have to replace the AT firmware with firmware that responds to the commands you want to send.

Comment: Yes, you replaced the AT firmware with your own (adafruit's) custom firmware. You have successfully directly programmed the ESP8266.

Comment: Ohh okay so that is why it is not responding to my AT commands anymore.  Just one last thing please.  If I retain my current setup with an Arduino and the custom firmware from the https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.4_a/esp8266wifi/readme.html in my ESP 8266.  Then how can I connect thru the internet from my Arduino code since AT command is not available anymore.  I could not find any google links to do this.  I always see AT commands.  I spent 2 days reading on this subject for my project.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You write your own software for the ESP8266 that accepts commands through serial (which you define) and does things according to those commands.

Comment: Oooohh okay... so the logic goes like this.  I program a series of functions in my ESP-8266 like connectToWifi() and in my loop() function I watched for messages from Serial.  What ever messages I received from serial corresponds to the function that I will be calling.  I then burn those program in my ESP.  I go back to Arduino, set the Board to Arduino Uno and in my loop, I will be sending a mesage serially like connectToWifi() and my ESP will received this and call the corresponding function and return it back to the Arduino Uno serially also.  Is this the pattern?

Comment: I spent two days already on this and I really don't like the examples in using the AT command.  However there is no documentation that I have seen or I might not be typing the correct search keys that would discuss the logic of defining your custom commands.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.  I have an ESP8266 sketch specifically for MQTT that does that kind of thing: https://github.com/MajenkoProjects/MQTTGateway

Comment: The point of defining your own custom commands is they are *your* commands. You define them how you want to define them and handle them how you want to handle them. They're just bytes arriving over serial.

Comment: This is really sweet mate.  I learned so much from you by just several minutes compare to the countless hours I have tried the past two days by trying all those AT commands that I don't like actually.  Thank you very much mate

Comment: https://imgflip.com/i/4cihtl ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have I not found any google hits from what you have laid out.  This could really help lots of beginning programmer.  From my perspective as a beginner, I was under the impression that the ESP8266 is just like any normal components with a library that you can call and add to your arduino with a defined API and not those quirky AT commands.  Anyhow than you very much again.

Comment: There is the basic assumption that you know the ESP8266 is just a microcontroller that is running firmware that exposes AT commands. Unless you already know that then googling for information is not easy.